# How can I use a Workflow Agent to send documents to one of 2 different export connectors in Kofax Capture 11

Tags: export, capture, kofax

We are using Kofax Capture 11 and have a use case where a number of documents come into the same PO box but they have 2 different paths they need to take upon export. We could use 2 different document classes in the batch class, with each document class exporting to the path required but that puts a lot of additional load on the imaging technicians. This batch class may have over 3,000 documents per day and the extra clicks would add up to about 45 minutes per day for the users.

Without using Total Agility or KTM, is it possible for a workflow agent to send the document to a different export connector based on either values of specific validation fields or just if a validation field is populated or not?

Comment: Would it be a possible solution to have different batch classes and insert the existing document class? As far as I know, the export connectors are configured per document class and batch class.

Answer (score 0):

You could;
A) Map a field that would only have a value if the doc needs to go that export route, forcing it to fail if the field is blank.  However, you would end up with a lot of docs in Partial Release status.
B) Create a validation script to copy the document as the other class.
C) Create a custom export connector.

Comment: Thanks Gerald. I agree that option A would not be optimal.

For option B) Create a validation script to copy the document as the other class, do you have a C# example of that? That sounds promising but I'm pretty limited in my validation script authoring at this point. Would it look at a value in the indexing and then if it fits the criteria it would change the doc class automatically for us? At what point would it do that? After indexing is completed or "on the fly" as it goes through the field that determines the doc class?

Comment: I do not have any sample code, sorry.
Yes, You could evaluate index field values and call a function to create a new document of whatever class you need, populate the index values from the old doc, etc.
The event could be triggered at field level, document level, or batch level. I think document level might be best for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks Gerald. I'll play around with that and see what I can come up with.